# Optimizing queries on larger MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, query-optimization

I'm coding a website which will store some offers (ex. job offers). In the end, it could contain more than 1M offers. Now I have problems with some inefficient SQL queries.

Scenario:

- Each offer can be assigned into category (ex. IT jobs)
- Each category has custom fields (ex. IT jobs can have custom field of type "price" which will represent text box accepting number (price) - in our example, let's say we have price input of expected salary)
- Each offer stores meta data with values of these category custom fields
- DB fields which will be used for filtering have indexes

**Table category (I'm using nested sets to store categories hierarchy):**

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `lft` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `rgt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `depth` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `order` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `category_parent_id_index` (`parent_id`),
 KEY `category_lft_index` (`lft`),
 KEY `category_rgt_index` (`rgt`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=44 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

**Table category_field:**

```
CREATE TABLE `category_field` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `optional` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `type` enum('price','number','date','color') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `category_field_category_id_index` (`category_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `category_field_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

**Table offer:**

```
CREATE TABLE `offer` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `text` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `offer_category_id_index` (`category_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `offer_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

**Table offer_meta:**

```
CREATE TABLE `offer_meta` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `offer_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `category_field_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `price` double NOT NULL,
 `number` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
 `color` varchar(7) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `offer_meta_offer_id_index` (`offer_id`),
 KEY `offer_meta_category_field_id_index` (`category_field_id`),
 KEY `offer_meta_price_index` (`price`),
 KEY `offer_meta_number_index` (`number`),
 KEY `offer_meta_date_index` (`date`),
 KEY `offer_meta_color_index` (`color`),
 CONSTRAINT `offer_meta_category_field_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_field_id`) REFERENCES `category_field` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `offer_meta_offer_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`offer_id`) REFERENCES `offer` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=107769 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

When I set up some filters on my page (for example, for our salary custom field) I have to start with query which returns MIN and MAX prices in available offer_meta records (I want to show a range slider to user in front-end, so I need MIN/MAX values for this range):

```
select MIN(`price`) AS min, MAX(`price`) AS max from `offer_meta` where `category_field_id` = ? limit 1
```

I found out that these queries are most inefficient from all queries I'm making (above query takes over 500ms when offer_meta table has few thousand of records).

**Other inefficient queries (offer_meta has 107k records):**

Obtaining MIN and MAX values for slider to filter numbers

```
select MIN(`number`) AS min, MAX(`number`) AS max from `offer_meta` where `category_field_id` = ? limit 1
```

Obtaining MIN and MAX prices for slider to filter by prices

```
select MIN(`price`) AS min, MAX(`price`) AS max from `offer_meta` where `category_field_id` = ? limit 1
```

Obtaining MIN and MAX date for date range restrictions

```
select MIN(`date`) AS min, MAX(`date`) AS max from `offer_meta` where `category_field_id` = ? limit 1
```

Obtaining colors with counts to show list of colors with numbers

```
select `color`, count(*) as `count` from `offer_meta` where `category_field_id` = ? group by `color`
```

**Example of full query to get offers count with multiple filter criteria (0.5 sec)**

```
select count(*) as count from `offer` where id in (select
                            distinct offer_id
                        from offer_meta om
                        where offer_id in (select
                            distinct offer_id
                        from offer_meta om
                        where offer_id in (select
                            distinct offer_id
                        from offer_meta om
                        where offer_id in (select
                            distinct om.offer_id
                        from offer_meta om
                        join category_field cf on om.category_field_id = cf.id
                        where
                            cf.category_id in (2,3,4,41,43,5,6,7,8,37) and
                            om.category_field_id = 1 and
                            om.number >= 1 and
                            om.number <= 50) and 
                            om.category_field_id = 2 and
                            om.price >= 2 and
                            om.price <= 4545) and 
                            om.category_field_id = 3 and
                            om.date >= '0000-00-00' and
                            om.date <= '2015-04-09') and 
                            category_field_id = 4 and
                            om.color in ('#0000ff'))
```

The same query without aggregation function (COUNT) is few times faster (just to get IDs).

**Question:**

Is it possible to tweak those queries, or do you have any suggestion on how to implement my logic (offers with categories and custom fields dynamically added in admin to each category) with different table schema? I tried few more schemes, but no success.

**Question 2:**

Do you think this is my MySQL server problem and if I buy VPS, it will be okay?

**Help to understand even better:**

I was strongly inspired by WordPress schema for custom fields, so the logic is similar.

**Last notes:**

Also, I'm working on Laravel framework and I'm using Eloquent ORM.
Sorry for my english, I hope I made my problem clear :-)

Thank you in advance,
Patrik

Comment: I know this isnt your question, but would you consider using something else than Mysql for that ? I would highly suggest you to use a search engin like Solr or ElasticSearch. It would be much easier and better performance wise in my humble opinion.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but in current situation, in which I'd have to re-model whole DB (or not?) this is not an option. I'll try to struggle with this problem and post some results in case I'll solve it.

Comment: Yes, however modeling with a search engine like Solr or Elasticsearch is easier than with relational db. You would be defining a flat document.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for all the tables; it will provide more info than your screen shots.  And provide the SELECTs that are giving you trouble.  From those, I can more easily zero in on performance issues.

Comment: I edited my post and added required information. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a MySql problem. in your scenario we found huge data collection. naturally relational databases are not efficient for some queries.(i faced a situation with oracle)
the practice for win this kind of situations is using graph databases. 
it seems it is hard with the situation you are facing at the movement. 
I heard that the Lucene has some kind of support for indexing large databases for selecting purpose. i dont know how exactly do it.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucene

Comment: Just so you know, Solr & Elastic search are both based on Lucene.